# Square Connect: How to retrieve product information from transaction id?

Tags: php, laravel, square-connect

I am able to checkout successfully using sandbox. And it returns me the checkoutId and transactionId.

```
//Dummy data

[

    'checkoutId' => 123123123,

    'transactionId' => 123123123 

]
```

I now need to retrieve the information about the transaction like Product details. How can I get that information from transaction id?

I research it on [Square Checkout Documentation](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/checkout-api/build-with-checkout) but unable to find any information.

**Edit**

Found a similar question [Stackoverflow asked by Gabriel Prieto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166643/checkout-api-get-email-of-buyer-on-redirect), but the accepted answer is [now deprecated](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2#type-transaction).

Comment: you have to use one to many relationship. for more details check out the documentation of laravel. from here you can see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many.........     If you face any problem let me know

Comment: @TanvirAhmed How do I retrieve transaction from Square API?

Comment: Sorry bro i did not use Square API.. So either my answer will be correct or not i cant say... Please wait fir others to respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransactionId is now equivalent to OrderId. The easiest solution here is to pass the `transactionId` to [BatchRetrieveOrders](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2#endpoint-orders-batchretrieveorders) and you'll get the information you need like itemization.